# At child Activity finish prevent screen lock

Tags: android

I have one activity (a) that launches another activity (b).  When the "b" activity finishes a timed event it closes.   All good there - the issue is that both are set to keep the screen on all the time, but when "b" closes and the time for screen lock-out has passed, the screen locks, i,e, "a" never gets the chance to reassert its "screen-on" command.  I've also tried setting android:keepScreenOn="true" in the manifest but doesn't work either...

Perhaps related when debugging and in screen "b" (the "child" activity), if I terminate the app from within the debugger, only screen "b" closes... shouldn't it kill the whole app?

Comment: Can you provide the code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... the WakeLock was unregistering at screen "a" close - which it needs to do if the whole app is unloading of course.  So I put a bool flag in screen "a", then in the onclick to open child "b" set the flag to true.  Then in the onActivityResult set the flag back to false.  Finally any close in "a" would would only unregister the wakelock if the flag was set to false...